# I Want To Give A Unique Name To Divs Which Are Rendering Dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I Am Using asp.net mvc3 . I am rendering a partial view by using foreach loop . So the thing i want to do is that i have a div in my partial view every time when partial rendered a new div is placed into the page . I just want to give every div a unique name . Can Anyone Help Me Out ?????? 
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you have something in the model used by your partial view that is unique - then in your partial view all you need is

```
<div name="div_@(Model.SomeUniqueId)"></div>
```

If there is nothing appropriate in the model, you can use the ViewBag:

```
@{
var i = 0;
foreach (var item in Model.Items) {
    ViewBag.UniqueId=i++;
    Html.RenderPartial("PartialView", item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your partial view, you could have the div defined as per below:

```
<div id="<%=Guid.NewGuid().ToString() %>"></div>
```

that way, you don't have to care about the model doing any extra lifting to populate the div **id**. also, note that i used **id** as the unique placeholder. divs don't have a '**name**' attribute, so be careful to make a note of that.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create DIV dynamically with the help of javascript

Following is the sample code that will help you

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<title>Create DIV Dynamically Using JavaScript</title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">   

  function DynamicDiv() {       
        var dynDiv = document.createElement("div");
        dynDiv.id = "divDyna";
        dynDiv.innerHTML = "Created using JavaScript";
        dynDiv.style.height = "20px";
        dynDiv.style.width = "300px";     
        dynDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
        document.body.appendChild(dynDiv);
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <input id="Button1" type="button"
        value="Using JS" onclick="DynamicDiv();" />    

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: -1 This is not ASP.NET MVC and does not even generate unique names.

Comment: This is not help full to me because every div created have same id "divDyna". I need Unique id.